# How to download an image/media using telegram API

Tags: download, telegram

I want to start by saying that this question is **not** for telegram bot API. I am trying to fetch images from a channel using telegram core API. The image is in the media property of the message object

```
"_": "message",
      "pFlags": {
        "post": true
      },
      "flags": 17920,
      "post": true,
      "id": 11210,
      "to_id": {
        "_": "peerChannel",
        "channel_id": 1171605754
      },
      "date": 1550556770,
      "message": "",
      "media": {
        "_": "messageMediaPhoto",
        "pFlags": {},
        "flags": 1,
        "photo": {
          "_": "photo",
          "pFlags": {},
          "flags": 0,
          "id": "6294134956242348146",
          "access_hash": "11226369941418527484",
          "date": 1550556770,
```

I am using the upload.getFile API to fetch the file. Example is

```
upload.getFile({
  location: {
    _: 'inputFileLocation',
    id: '6294134956242348146',
    access_hash: '11226369941418527484'
  },
  limit: 1000,
  offset: 0
})
```

But the problem is it throws the error **RpcError: CODE#400 LIMIT_INVALID**. From looking at the https://core.telegram.org/api/files it looks like limit value is invalid. I tried giving limit as

- 1024000 (1Kb)
- 20480000 (20Kb)
- 204800000 (200kb)

But it always return the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is also frustrated with the docs. Using, reading and trying out different stuff will ultimately work for you. If possible someone can take up the task of documenting the wonderful open source software.

Coming to the answer, the location object shouldn't contain id or access hash like other APIs rather it has its own parameters as defined in telegram schema.

There is a media property to a message which has a sizes object. This will contains 3 or more size options (thumbnail, preview, websize and so on). Choose the one that you will need and use the volume_id, local_id and secret properties. The working code will look something like this.

```
upload.getFile({
    location: {
      _: 'inputFileLocation', (This parameter will change for other files)
      volume_id: volumeId,
      local_id: localId,
      secret: secret
    },
    limit: 1024 * 1024,
    offset: 0
  }, {
    isFileTransfer: true,
    createClient: true
  })
```

The following points should be noted.

- Limit should be in bytes (not bits)
- Offset will be 0. But if its big file use this and limit to download parts of the file and join them.
- Additional parameters such as isFileTransfer and createClient also exists. I haven't fully understood why its needed. If I have time I'll update it later.

Try using a library that's built on top the original telegram library. I'm using [Airgram](https://github.com/airgram/airgram), a JS/TS library which is a well maintained Repo.